# How to calculate DNI and DHI from GHI data in pvLIB?

Tags: python, pvlib

I've done some of the pvlib tutorials, but at this moment I would like to calculate the pv power based on a database, which only has global horizontal irradiance.

The data looks as follows:

[image]

Also wind speed and temperature data are available.

I was wondering how I can calculate the direct normal irradiance (dni) and the diffuse horizontal irradiance (dhi) from this data, since I can't find any documentation on this topic. If I have the dni and dhi I can calculate my pv power from there using pvlib functions.

The data shown above is from Amsterdam:

lat: 52.37

lon:4.895

tz: 'Europe/Amsterdam'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the [DNI estimation models](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#dni-estimation-models).

Comment: Link is dead now. Please try ERBS function : https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/pvlib.irradiance.erbs.html?highlight=erbs#pvlib.irradiance.erbs